# Local repository with Git

Tags: git, repository, workspace

I would like to use Git in my local computer such that,
`H:\Projects\projectname` will be my server-like repository and I would like work by cloning this repo to `C:\Users\xxx\AptanaProjects\projectname`

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a bare repository on H:. With git you usually name your bare repository with .git, so projectname.git in this case:

```
h:
cd \Projects\
mkdir projectname.git
cd projectname.git
git init --bare
```

When this is done you change to c to create your repository:

```
c:
cd \Users\xxx\AptanaProjects\projectname
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
```

After this you need to setup the bare repo on h: as the remote repository so you can push up the code you just commited to the repo on c:

```
git remote add origin H:\Projects\projectname.git
git push origin master
```

Now, someone else can clone from H: to get your changes, and their repos will automatically be setup with the repo on H: as their origin.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Git if you haven't already
2. With e.g. TortoiseGit, initialize a repository in `H:\Projects\projectname` ("Git create repository here" in the context menu)
3. Clone that repository to your working directory, e.g. `C:\Users\xxx\AptanaProjects\projectname` ("Git Clone..." in the context menu)
4. You're done.

Now when you work, commit in your working directory and then Git Push to send your changes to `H:\ Projects`.

I'm assuming you have a valid reason for having that projects directory and not just versioning your projects in the working directory?

Comment: ...yeah, I went ahead and assumed that: 1) Aptana will let you create a project in a directory that already exists, and 2) You haven't in fact already got a git-versioned project that you just want to copy to `H:\Projects`

Comment: Actually I just want versioning my projects. I would like to recover my mistakes in my workspace by keeping a running copy in other place. Is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: You don't need to have a separate "remote" repository for that: with Git, any clone (including the one you're working in) will contain the whole history, so you can recover from your mistakes without having a clone. Of course, if you e.g. accidentally delete the project and don't have a clone, your work is lost. Versioning without a clone works fine, however. I guess the crucial point here is that with Git (or any DVCS), all clones are basically equivalent: they all contain the whole history.

Answer (score 0):

Enter directory `C:\Users\xxx\AptanaProjects\projectname` and use:

```
git clone H:\Projects\projectname
```

or using file protocol `file://`

Look at http://progit.org/ for free documentation.